# Expected time it takes a continuous Markov Chain to reach a state

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, markov-chains

For the continuous time Markov Chain (CTMC) $\{X(t), t \geq 0\}$ with state space $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and generator matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 1& 0&0&0\\
1&-2&1&0&0\\
3/4&0&-3&3/2&3/4\\
1&0&0&-4&3\\
0&0&5/2&5/2&-5
\end{bmatrix}
we are asked to find $E[\tau_0|X_0=1]$, where $\tau_0 = inf\{t>0: X(t) = 0\}$. In previous parts of this problem we found the one step transition matrix and the stationary distribution of the embedded DTMC, and the stationary distribution of the CTMC. I was wondering if I could use this information to find $E[\tau_0|X_0=1]$? My original approach to answer this questions was to use first step analysis; however, it became a bit tedious to keep up with the steps towards the end. This made me think that maybe I am missing a link between the previous parts and this questions.